# Android Action Bar won't show items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I cannot get icons to show in the action bar.

I am using the most recent SDK with eclipse.

I am trying to do this tutorial
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

My MainActivity.java is

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }    
}
```

My main.xml under menu is

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="always" >
    </item>

</menu>
```

But I dont see the menu items.  It looks like this
[image: menu missing items]
Any help on how to get these menu items shows would be useful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

> The showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace
>   defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML
>   attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do
>   not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use
>   your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the
>   support library.

So do the following modifications:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          yourapp:showAsAction="always" >
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thank you Benito.

I tried that implementation but still no icons are visible.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you must have already done this, but did you download the icons and put them inside your res > drawable folders? If you are using a dark action bar, be sure to install the light colored icons and vice versa.
I followed the same tutorial and it works for me. Your code looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

and change

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is here:

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

change it to this:

```
return Boolean.TRUE;
```

Source: [Menus in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) and an old project of mine.

Comment: Thank you Joseph.

I tried that change and still no menu items :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the tutorial too, I think the mistake is here:

```
// Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

It should be

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

It also took me a while for this issue after I followed the tutorial step by step. Funny how, my problem is that I used light color search button image while chose the dark Holo theme. Therefore, my search button simply becomes invisible (it is there) in the dark background. You may try to adjust your theme if you encouter same issue.